# Access DataFrame Data Using Relative Indexes

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use information about a row to inform which other data throughout a DataFrame to look at.

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,5,9],'b':[2,6,3],'c':[0,7,1]})

   a  b  c
0  1  2  0
1  5  6  7
2  9  3  1
```

I would like to ask something like:
What is the value at the next index location for the highest value in each row.

The result might look something like this:

```
   a  b  c data
0  1  2  0    6
1  5  6  7    1
2  9  3  1  NaN
```

The largest number at index `0` is `2`, and `6` is found in the same column at the next index location.

The largest number at index `1` is `7`, and `1` is found in the same column at the next index location.

And there is no data after index `2` so nothing is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.idxmax` to find the column of the maximum value for each row, and then use `df.lookup` to find the value in the next row within the same column.

```
import pandas as pd

# Ignore the last row
lookups = df.idxmax(axis=1)[:-1]
#0    b
#1    c
#dtype: object

df['data'] = pd.Series(df.lookup(lookups.index+1, lookups))
#   a  b  c  data
#0  1  2  0   6.0
#1  5  6  7   1.0
#2  9  3  1   NaN
```